# Getting "Can't open this video" when attempting to open a video

Tags: video

Video with extension VOB and transferred from my PC to the tab doesn't open in latter. When I attempt to open it I get "Can't open this video" and "No thumbnail".

How to play that video in my phone?

Comment: 1) What is the extension of that video file? 2) Do you have a video player app that can play a file with that extension?  3) What file manager are you using? My stock file manager doesn't allow me to open an MKV video even when I've MX Player installed.

Comment: The extension is .VOB , I am not using any special player app , I just send videos from my laptop to my android tablet and I can just view it in the gallery.So far I've been doing it , but now it says no thumbnails.

Answer (score -1):

Use a video player app, such as  VLC for Android and MX Player.

Comment: Looks like an answer to me.  VLC plays a lot of videos that don't work in bundled video player apps on Android.

Comment: No i haven't tried that yet , I'll try it and get back to you , thank you..